# Why my object is not updated in linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a method where I READ objects from DB, for instance:

```
public Object getProduct(int categoryId, int productId)
{
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(Settings.getDefaultConnectionStringName());

        switch (categoryId)
        {
            case CCategorii.CARTI_ID:
                {
                    IEnumerable<Carti> product = (from c in db.Cartis
                                                  where c.Carti_id == productId
                                                  && c.Vizibil == true
                                                  select c);

                    if (product.Count() != 0)
                        return product.First();

                    break;
                }
           //so on
        }
}
```

Now I have another method where I do the update:

```
public void updateProduct()
{
   Object productToBeUpdated = getProduct(1,1);
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(Settings.getDefaultConnectionStringName());
   //update some properties of the product
   productToBeUpdated.setQuantity(productToBeUpdated.getQuantity()+1);
   db.submitChanges();
}
```

Well, the product was succcesfully read from previous method but changes were not done into the DB.

I think the cause is that I do this READ-UPDATE in two different DataContext...*If this is the cause how do you threat this situations?*

Oh yeah, I can read the product and update in the same method but this means to duplicate the method I use for reading and add to it update stuff... and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: create one instance of db and update it......you are editing one instance and saving the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different instances of your DataContext.

When implementing a web app, the best option is usually to align the lifetime of your DataContext to the lifetime of one http request. The lifetime you use is just too short.

Another option is to attach the object to the write DataContext:

```
db.Cartis.Attach(yourReadObject);
updateProperties(yourReadObject);
db.submitChanges();
```

**EDIT**

Ok, you have to detach the object from your other context first. See [this article](http://omaralzabir.com/linq_to_sql__how_to_attach_object_to_a_different_data_context/) on how to do it.

But i really would recommend to use a single DataContext object and extend the lifetime to the httprequest scope.

This can be done really nice with an ioc container like [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/).

Comment: Seems that this is not supported: `An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.`

Answer (score 3):

I would assume it's because you are using a different context for the read and write. Try moving your `DataClassesDataContext` variable to class level.

Comment: this seems to be the best solution.... @chritian , do this and you are good enough to rock and roll

Comment: Yes, it's good if the methods are in the same class. If not, Zruty's solution seems better.

Comment: hmm....in that case you will have to pass the datacontext but within a class, it's much better

Comment: @Cristian these methods work on the same object type and data context - this is a good hint that they *should* be in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

One option is: use a common data context, and pass it to your getXXX methods as a parameter:

```
public Object getProduct(DataClassesDataContext db, int categoryId, int productId)
{
    switch (categoryId)
    {
        case CCategorii.CARTI_ID:
            {
                IEnumerable<Carti> product = (from c in db.Cartis
                                              where c.Carti_id == productId
                                              && c.Vizibil == true
                                              select c);

                if (product.Count() != 0)
                    return product.First();

                break;
            }
       //so on
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public void updateProduct()
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(Settings.getDefaultConnectionStringName()))
    {
       Object productToBeUpdated = getProduct(db, 1,1);
       //update some properties of the product
       productToBeUpdated.setQuantity(productToBeUpdated.getQuantity()+1); // THX @AVD, didn't notice that.
       db.submitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ++ operator and use the same context to update an object. Try this,

```
productToBeUpdated.setQuantity(productToBeUpdated.getQuantity()+1);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is because I wrote the code here. But any other property is not updated. I met this situations in different projects I had and this was just an example..

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your DataContext goes out of scope your entity becomes detached from it. That means it's no longer being tracked by your Context and it can't save the changes you make to it.

You could share the context so the entity doesn't get detached from your context or you could reattach it to the second context ([DataContext.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx))